# How to create multiple tables in SQLITE for ionic angular

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to make multiple tables in SQLITE in my ionic project, but it appears that this format is not working; does anyone have any ideas on how to create multiple tables in SQLITE in an ionic project? thank you very much

```
 databaseConn() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.sqlite.create({
              name: this.db_name,
              location: 'default'
            }).then((sqLite: SQLiteObject) => {
              this.dbInstance = sqLite;
              sqLite.executeSql(`
                  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${this.db_table} (
                   product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
                  product_name varchar(255),
                  product_price varchar(255)
                  )`, []) 
                .then((res) => {
                  // alert(JSON.stringify(res));
                })
                .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
        });   

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.sqlite.create({
              name: this.db_name,
              location: 'default'
            }).then((sqLite: SQLiteObject) => {
              this.dbInstance = sqLite;
                  sqLite.executeSql(`
                   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${this.db_table2} (
                  customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
                  customer_name varchar(255)
              
                )`, [])   
                .then((res) => {
                  // alert(JSON.stringify(res));
                })
                .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
        });   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this.platform.ready hook will trigger only one time after your device is ready.

**ready() => Promise​**

> Returns a promise when the platform is ready and native functionality
> can be called. If the app is running from within a web browser, then
> the promise will resolve when the DOM is ready. When the app is
> running from an application engine such as Cordova, then the promise
> will resolve when Cordova triggers the deviceready event. The resolved
> value is the readySource, which states the platform that was used.
>
> For example, when Cordova is ready, the resolved ready source is
> cordova. The default ready source value will be dom. The readySource
> is useful if different logic should run depending on the platform the
> app is running from. For example, only Capacitor and Cordova can
> execute the status bar plugin, so the web should not run status bar
> plugin logic.
>
> The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the
> event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs. Applications
> typically attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once
> the HTML document's DOM has loaded.

```
databaseConn() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.sqlite.create({
            name: this.db_name,
            location: 'default'
        }).then((sqLite: SQLiteObject) => {
            this.dbInstance = sqLite;
            this.createTable(
                `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${this.db_table} (
                   product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
                  product_name varchar(255),
                  product_price varchar(255)
                )`
            );

            this.createTable(
                `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${this.db_table2} (
                  customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
                  customer_name varchar(255)
                )`
            );
        })
            .catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
    });
}

createTable(tableStr: string): void {
    this.dbInstance.executeSql(`${tableStr}`, []).then((res) => {
        console.log('table was created')
    })
    .catch(e => {
        alert("error " + JSON.stringify(e))
    })
}
```

Comment: I can understand and can see the flow, tried to do the exact same thing as you but it is not working :(

Comment: may i know your ionic version please?

Comment: ionic 6, db_table is working but not db_table2